# Close react-pro-sidebar when clicking outside

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sidebar

Here is code

```
import { ProSidebar } from 'react-pro-sidebar';
...
const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);
<ProSidebar toggled={toggle} breakPoint='md' ... >
...
```

When toggle is false, Sidebar will close.

How can I close sidebar when clicking outside?

Need Standard coding. Not ax carpenter.

You can check detail on this online site.

https://healer-nft-game.onrender.com

Comment: i guess sth like this? `<ProSidebar toggled={toggle} style={{ visibility: toggle ? 'visible' : 'hidden' }} />`?

Answer (score 0):

react-pro-sidebar provides a prop function called onBackdropClick to achieve this. you can set your toggle state change inside this function will be enough to get done this.

```
<Sidebar
    toggled={toggle}
    onBackdropClick={() => setToggle((prev) => !prev)}
  >
```